# How do i know if the input is an character or a float number with scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator without any errors but in addition, per example, if I input an "a" the program has an unexpected output.
Basically my question is what can I do for the program to show up a warning when I input a character.
Maybe the `scanf` return any useful value?

Comment: If you want enter to mean "calculate this line", use `getline` or `fgets` to read the line. Then parse it, possibly using `sscanf`, possibly something else.

Comment: "make a simple calculator without any errors" --> `scanf()` is difficult to use error free.  The easier approach is to read a _line_ of user input with `fgets()` and then parse the _string_,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the flags scanf is providing to scan integers.

```
int main()
{
    float nb;

    if (scanf("%f", &v) == 1) {
        printf("Is float !\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not a float !\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

scanf returns the number of flags successfuly reads, so if this number is different than 1 (in this example), that means scanf couldn't convert your input in float.

In the case of an addition:

```
int main()
{
    float a;
    float b;

    if (scanf("%f +%f", &a, &b) == 2) {
        printf("Result is %f\n", a + b);
    } else {
        printf("Error !\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> This works but you have to write the exact scanf string. I suggest you
>   to read the input line as a string instead, and then parse it using
>   strtol or other functions.

Comment: `"%f +%f"` is more white-space tolerant than `"%f+%f"`.